# Strange wiggles on the surface of a ParametricPlot3D

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I'm trying to plot two cones but when I try to display them, Mathematica (10) makes the edges wiggly.

My code is:

```
bicone = ParametricPlot3D[{(1 - Abs[z]) Cos[t], (1 - Abs[z]) Sin[t], z}, 
{z, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
Mesh -> None,
MaxRecursion -> 8,
Boxed -> False,
Axes -> None,
PlotStyle -> {Specularity[White, 15], Opacity[0.4]}];

Show[bicone, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ViewVector -> {0, -10, 0.75}]
```

And here is the result with the strange wiggles:

[image: bicone with strange wiggles]

Comment: It may be an anti-aliasing problem. Have you tried Mathematica / Preferences / Appearance /  Graphics and move the slider over to "Highest Quality"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need more points, not recursion.

If you increase the number of `PlotPoints` and add `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`, the wiggles disappear!

```
bicone = ParametricPlot3D[{(1 - Abs[z]) Cos[t], (1 - Abs[z]) Sin[t], z}, {z, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Mesh -> None,  Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> {Specularity[White, 15], Opacity[0.4]},
   MaxRecursion -> 2,  PlotPoints -> 400, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

Show[bicone, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ViewVector -> {0, -10, 0.75}]
```

> [image: WiggleFree]

The screenshot doesn't do it justice, though.